# Select item from JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to select an item from JSON response in javascript. I am calling a GET request and API is returing JSON.

GET API :- `https://autocomplete.clearbit.com/v1/companies/suggest?query=google.com`

JSON :- `[{"name":"Google","domain":"google.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/google.com"}]`

I want to select the value of `name` outside of function. This is my Javascript,

```
        var theUrl = 'https://autocomplete.clearbit.com/v1/companies/suggest?query=';
        var q = "google.com";
        function httpGet(theUrl, q)
       {
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl+q, false ); // false for synchronous request
            xmlHttp.send( null );

            return xmlHttp.responseText;
       }

       var a = httpGet(theUrl, q);
       console.log(a.name);
```

But, `a.name` is returning `undefined`

Comment: "false for synchronous request" — Danger: This is deprecated functionality that has an adverse effect on sites. Do not do that.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty — It is not an asynchronous call!

Comment: Yeah I rescinded the close vote half a day ago but the automatically generated comment remained

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are trying to read the `name` property of a **string**.

To convert JSON into a JavaScript data structure, you must parse it (with the `JSON.parse()` method).

---

After you have done that, you need to be looking in the right part of the data structure.

The JSON consists of an array, containing an object, which has a name property.

You have to extract the object from the array before you can read its name property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the response from google as JSON to turn it into an object, like so:

```
var theUrl = 'https://autocomplete.clearbit.com/v1/companies/suggest?query=';
var q = "google.com";

function httpGet(theUrl, q) {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl+q, false ); // false for synchronous request
  xmlHttp.send( null );
  try {
    return JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
}

var a = httpGet(theUrl, q);
if (a && a.length) {
  console.log(a[0].name);
} else {
  console.log('no results found');
}
```

Google also returns an array so you must do `a[0].name` and not `a.name`, and for good measure, we will add safety checks to make sure google actually returns JSON to us and that it in fact has at least 1 item in it before trying to print the name.